# Run a PHP script once every minute

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I need to execute my PHP code every minute. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: voting to close: x-duplicate and belongs on serverfault

Comment: ssh: crontab -e : * * * * * wget http://www.mypage.com/cron.php

Comment: Why not use a cronjob for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run PHP code from the command line. e.g., if your PHP folder is in PATH:

```
php.exe C:\mycode\myfile.php
```

You can then set this up as a scheduled task in windows.
Side note: be aware that certain things don't exist (and something exist in their place), e.g. Apache or IIS objects, as well as the full range of HTTP stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Set up a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job.

Comment: If the OP is new to PHP, he should be aware that Cron can have a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Shibin Moideen, there are some cron implementations for windows (plus the built-in task scheduler), I'd recommend nncron lite or sinc (sinc is not cron (this is the name))

Comment: @roddik - Recursive acronyms are irritating.  Gah.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use cron; you could write a script to call it at the top of the minute

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]; do 
  if [ $(expr $(date +%s) % 60) -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "top o da minute";
    #put php script here
  fi; 
  sleep 1; 
done
```

Advantage/Disadvantage is that you will only spawn one copy of the script if it takes longer than a minute to complete.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
```

A very simple solution would be to add this html tag to your page. The page will reload every `content` seconds, and of course, execute again the php code.

Comment: Easy and recommended solution.