# Fetch data every n minutes using PHP

Tags: php

How can I fetch number of shares every 5 minutes for specified URL?

Here is my code for getting number of shares from twitter:

```
function twittershares($url) {

 $s = file_get_contents("http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json".
 "?callback=?&url=".urlencode($url));

 preg_match("#(\"count\"):([0-9]*)#",$s,$ar);

 return isset($ar[2]) ? $ar[2] : 0;
 }

 echo twittershares("http://abc1234.com");
```

Thanks

Comment: You can also call this function for example from Ajax every 5 minutes.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1521943/1401975)

Comment: @Voitcus, that means, You must keep browser open.

Comment: @Guntis I know, I was expecting that he wants to update his page with this value.

Comment: @Voitcus, I will use the updated value in database, so it should work in backend.

Comment: @prateek so use cron on Linux or sheduled tasks on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to set up a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run every x minutes - whatever you want - and the cron job will call your script which will run the code you want at that time interval.

This is a tutorial I used when I started learning: [Tutorial on setting up cron job](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)

One last edit, this is what the URL of your cron job might look like:

```
wget -N http://yoursite.com/yourscript.php
```

Answer (score 0):

well you have two option using pure php
1.Cron job, like ppl have already written or
2. Something more exotic , [writing a small php daemon](http://stuporglue.org/writing-a-daemon-with-php/) , in case you need to make requests
to many urls at the same time.

Comment: I have many links to track will php daemon be better or is there someother way to handle around 350 requests at a time?

Comment: well in that case, you better create a distributed system, with some queue  like rabbitmq, here is a tutorial http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html  , it's for python, but there is a php client too